# Fields for an athletic 'Race' Time, and converting to a Float

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

**If a Track Athlete was saving their race times after a Track meet...**

The athlete selects/enters *'MM:SS:ss'* into a field.

I need to save it as a float (of seconds) in the database.

800M: ( *'01:48.37'* --to-- 108.37 )

100M: ( *'00:10.59'* --to-- 10.59 )

10,000M: ( *'27:08.11'* --to-- 1628.11 )

--

I havent found a straightforward or reliable way that allows a User to input that kind of time, then convert the object to a float before_save. Can I make this work, or is there a better way to do do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your problem, converting times from one format to another, or organizing your `result` model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails allows you to store datatypes as `float`. You just have to handle the conversion.

How are you submitting the data? As what type? If you were submitting a string you could just do something like this:

```
min, sec, centi = "1:23:45".split(":")

seconds = (min.to_i * 60) + sec.to_i + (centi.to_f / 100)
```

Comment: I don't mean to nitpick, but 45 in your example are not milliseconds, but centiseconds. :)